# Dynamically change value for RadDatePicker using Jquery

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, telerik

```
<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2">
<telerik:RadDatePicker ID="dtStatuschange" Calendar-Enabled="false"  runat="server" Width="128%" Culture="en-US" DateInput-ReadOnly="true"></telerik:RadDatePicker>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2">
 <telerik:RadComboBox ID="comboStatus" runat="server" Width="128%" CssClass="labelStyle" ForeColor="#083772" OnClientSelectedIndexChanged="StatusChanged" </telerik:RadComboBox>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function StatusChanged(sender, eventArgs)
{
  var d = new Date();
  var date = d.getDate() + "/" + (d.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + d.getFullYear();
  $("#dtStatuschange").val(date);            

}
</script>
```

I have a situation like if i change the values in status comboBox, the current date should be assingned to dtStatuschange.I tried using javascript, but the date remains unchanged

Answer (score 0):

What i understand from your question is that you are trying to add one month with current date and set it to `RadDatepicker` with `combobox` change event. please try below code. No need for `OnClientSelectedIndexChanged="StatusChanged"` event.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#comboStatus').on('change', function (e) {
    var today = new Date();
    today.setMonth(today.getMonth() + 1);
    var date = $find("<%=dtStatuschange.ClientID %>");
    date.set_selectedDate(today);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Hi Nagib ...I tried this but the value in dtStatuschange remains unchanged

Comment: Are you using `MasterPage` with your page? because i tried this and it works. If you are using master page select id like `"[id$=comboStatus]"` then it should work.